# Mark Complete Flag in Outlook 2013

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-outlook

My question is similar to one posted by   Courtney Duell Jul 23 '14 at 21:06.

> Courtney wrote: Previously, the follow up 'flags' had multiple flag
>   options, as well as the capability to set reminders with them and a
>   'check mark' option to mark an email complete.

I find myself in exactly the same situation.

I recently purchased a new computer and changed OS from WIN7 to WIN8.  I re-installed Outlook 2013 using the same disc. I used to have multiple followup flag options, including the Mark Complete flag, now I have only the red followup flag option.  I'm wondering if this is a WIN8 issue?

Answer (score 1):

In Outlook 2013, if you right click on the message, there if a `Follow Up` option. If you select that, you can specify the finer options in `Follow Up`. If you click on the flag icon in the e-mail row, it cycles between Follow Up and Mark Complete.

If you select `Set Quick Click...` you can specify when you want to Follow Up. For example, if I `Set Quick Click...` to `Next Week`, then clicking on the Flag icon on the email row will cycle between Flag for Follow Up Next Week and Mark Complete.

Hope that helps.

[image]

Comment: These are also shown on the toolbar so you don't need two clicks to get to them.

Comment: I do not yet know how to add a screen shot but suffice it to say, I do not have the pick list of due dates or Mark Complete under the Follow Up menu item.  I did under WIN7 but now with WIN8 I only have "Flag Message" and "Clear Flag."

Comment: Sounds like a Win 8 issue? The screenshot is from Windows 7, Outlook 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: it depends on what type of Outlook account do you use. It works for Exchange and POP3 but not working for EAS (outlook.com) and IMAP. And it doesn't depend on OS version at all.

Comment: Thanks thims, this was the solution to my issue.  I created a new POP3 account, copied folders and removed my IMAP account. I always thought IMAP superior to POP3 but, at least in this case, POP3 has the functionality I want.  Thank you again for posting.